# Singleton Session object as JSON using C#

Tags: c#, json

I have a singleton class which stores my session data like below

```
public sealed class SessionData
{
    private const string SESSION_KEY = "SOME_KEY";

    public static SessionData Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session[SESSION_KEY] != null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session[SESSION_KEY] = new SessionData();
            }
            return (SessionData)HttpContext.Current.Session[SESSION_KEY];
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible/right way to convert my object to JSON string, save it in Session and still have the data persisted in the object?

Comment: Will it ever change? How often? How often do you need the JSON?

Comment: Not an answer, but you better read [this article](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx) about singelton by Jon Skeet.

Comment: The idea is to reduce burden on session by saving a JSON string instead of an object

Comment: So this is an optimization? How big is the object and how often do you access the JSON?

Comment: So far the object isn't huge. Just wanted to make sure to have other ways of implementation before it gets huge